# VirtualBox - Error

Tags: virtualization

I am trying to run a VirtualBox inside another VirtualBox and I am getting the following error:

```
 VT-x is not available 
 (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

 Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
 Component: ConsoleWrap
 Interface: |Console {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

My original operating system is macOS, my first VirtualBox is running Kali Linux, and the VirtualBox that I am trying to set up is Kali Linux as well.

Comment: No sure if this will help you (given Thomas answer below), but VMWare Fusion does support nested virtualisation in VMWare fusion.

Comment: Does VMWare Fusion run on Linux?

Comment: VMWare Workstation works on Windows and Linux, while VMWare Fusion works on OSX. I'm not sure if the license works across these 2 products. It might worth asking if VirtualBox does run in a guest running VMWare Workstation/Fusion as VMWare does emulate VT-x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a Mac, you likely have an Intel CPU. VirtualBox does not support nested virtualization for Intel CPUs according to the Oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/nested-virt.html)

> Oracle VM VirtualBox supports nested virtualization on host systems
>   that run **AMD CPUs**

Comment: Would it support nested virtualization through VMWare Fusion?